# Delete cookies from past 1hr in chrome || Acess the chrome://settings/clearBrowserData to delete the data

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I select the elements and send keys in the chrome settings using selenium?

```
await driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
      await driver.findElement(By.id("clearBrowsingDataConfirm")).click();
```

I get the error

```
(node:50239) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
```

I am expecting the data from the last one hour to be deleted.